# Select a div from dynamically created div elements - Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, css-selectors

I am writing a code to create `div` elements dynamically using `*ngFor` directive like below:

```
<div *ngFor = "let item of Items">
<p>Item : {{item}} </p>
</div>
```

Now when I hover mouse on particular div part, that div part only needs to be highlited using some background colors.

If I use `mouseenter` attribute on `div` tag, it selects all the `div` elements rather than selecting the exact one which I hovered with the mouse.

```
 <div (mouseenter) ="hovered=true" 
       (mouseleave) ="hovered=false" 
       *ngFor = "let item of Items"  
       [style.background]="hovered? 'red' : none">
      <p>Item : {{item}} </p>
  </div>
```

So how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried CSS?

Comment: Yes I tried, it applies to all the div elements

Comment: show us your css

Comment: In that case your CSS is wrong

Comment: Didn't you get a compiler error when using `let item in Items`?

Comment: Here `hovered` variable is used in common by all divs generated by `ngFor` directive. So when you set `hovered=true` on `mouseenter` event, you are setting that variable to all the elements. Correct way would be to use CSS `:hover` selector as shown in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am wondering how your `*ngFor` itself works, reason is you are using `let item in Items` instead of `let item of Items` (It is `of` should not be `in`)

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor = "let item of Items">
  <p> Item: {{item}}  </p>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
div:hover{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

> [**Working Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-rvgipu)

Edit:

As per your edited question, you are assigning hover to all the elements, instead you need to assign hover to each separate element using their index for which you need to use like,

```
<div (mouseenter)="hover=i" (mouseleave)="hover=-1" *ngFor = "let item of Items;let i = index"
       [style.background]="hover=== i ? 'red' : none">
  <p> Item: {{item}}  </p>
</div>
```

Now you can achieve the result without any css and the working example as follows,

> [**Edited Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-destpl)

Comment: And I agree with your answer but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @SaravananKS, I have edited my answer.. Please check.. You need to use index in assigning ```hover``` to the elements..

Answer (score 3):

Use the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class

html

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <p class="hover-target">Item : {{item}} </p>
  <p>footer</p>
</div>
```

css

```css
.hover-target:hover {
  background-color: red;
  /* whatever styles you want to apply */
}
```

**Note** - your `*ngFor` syntax is wrong. It should be `*ngFor="let item of Items"`

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kp4zfv

Comment: And I agree with your answer but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not scoping the hover to a row - you're saying that the whole array is either hovered or it isn't

Comment: understood with index concept